# ContractResolver can alter the mapped property

Tags: c#, json.net

I want every property that doesn't have a `JsonPropertyAttribute` specified, to follow the custom contract. But if it is specified, then that is exactly what it should be.

But if I have a mapped property and am using a custom contract resolver, then the contract resolver can alter the mapped property.

For instance, when `JsonProperty("hello")` is specified, I should see `hello` in the JSON output. Instead, I see `hello_`. I filed an [issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/314), but was told to override a higher method instead, but not which one.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace DeserializeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var json = new JObject(new JProperty("hello", "world"));

            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver() };
           var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json.ToString(), settings);
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [JsonProperty("hello")]
        public string FooBar { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            return propertyName + "_";
        }
    }
}
```

So how would I get Json.NET to always use (and not alter) the `JsonProperty` when specified?

Real world example: I am using the [SnakeCamelCaseContractResolver](https://gist.github.com/crallen/9238178). It puts an underscore in between text and numbers. This mimics how Rails serializes. But in cases where the norm isn't followed, like `address1`, I need to be able to prevent the `SnakeCamelCaseContractResolver` from changing the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Andrew Whitaker has the correct idea here.  I'll add that if you want to get your `SnakeCamelCaseContractResolver` example to work, you could change the implementation to the following.  Notice it overrides `CreateProperty` instead of `ResolvePropertyName`.

```
class SnakeCaseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        // if the property does not have a JsonPropertyAttribute applied, use Snake Case
        if (!member.CustomAttributes.Any(att => att.AttributeType == typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute)))
        {
            prop.PropertyName = GetSnakeCase(prop.PropertyName);
        }

        return prop;
    }

    private string GetSnakeCase(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return input;

        var buffer = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            var isLast = (i == input.Length - 1);
            var isSecondFromLast = (i == input.Length - 2);

            var curr = input[i];
            var next = !isLast ? input[i + 1] : '\0';
            var afterNext = !isSecondFromLast && !isLast ? input[i + 2] : '\0';

            buffer += char.ToLower(curr);

            if (!char.IsDigit(curr) && char.IsUpper(next))
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(curr))
                {
                    if (!isLast && !isSecondFromLast && !char.IsUpper(afterNext))
                        buffer += "_";
                }
                else
                    buffer += "_";
            }

            if (!char.IsDigit(curr) && char.IsDigit(next))
                buffer += "_";
            if (char.IsDigit(curr) && !char.IsDigit(next) && !isLast)
                buffer += "_";
        }

        return buffer;
    }
}
```

**Demo**: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iqz9cA

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure what JNK means exactly by a "higher level method,"  but here's a stab at it overriding `CreateProperty`:

```
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(
        MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (!property.HasMemberAttribute || 
            property.PropertyName == property.UnderlyingName)
        {
            property.PropertyName += "_";
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Basically, call the base class' `CreateProperty` method, then check to see if the property has an attribute. Even if the property *does* have an attribute, there's no guarantee that the attribute specified a new property name, hence the comparison between `PropertyName` and `UnderlyingName`. If there's no attribute or the names are the same, then append the underscore.

Again I'm not sure if this is the correct place to do this, but it works and is simple enough.